# create flash by javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, object

I have this code, but doesn't work.

HTML block:

```
  <div id="div_container"></div>
```

JS

```
 var youtube_code = '<object width="434" height="309"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ&hl=es_AR&fs=1?rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ&hl=es_AR&fs=1?rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="434" height="309"></embed></object>';
  document.getElementById('div_container').innerHTML = youtube_code;
```

I really don't understand why. I'd tried it in all browsers(IE, FF, CHR,O). Not js errors happens. I can see in firebug or inspector that object node is created. But Flash plugin never appear.

Thanks

Comment: Saying 'doesn't work' really isn't helpful. You'll need to provide a lot more information. Tell us HOW it doesn't work - do you get a result you're not expecting, do you get no result at all? Give us more than a segment of one line worth of Javascript (at least the entire line) - you're attempting to reference a HTML element, provide the section of your HTML code that declares that element. Tell us which browser(s) you're testing with, what operating system, etc.

Comment: really good question, but I have always used SWFObject to embed flash.
Is it an IE browser issue ?

Comment: Anthony, you are right... I'd extended my explanation.

Comment: have you tried the iFrame approach on youtube?

Comment: yes kjy112, using the iframe works fine. But I have the curiosity to know why object insertion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
var youtube_code = '<object width="434" height="309">'+
'<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ&hl=es_AR&fs=1?rel=0" />'+
'<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />'+
'<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />'+
'<embed src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ&hl=es_AR&fs=1?rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="434" height="309">'+
'</embed>'+
'</object>';
var writeIt = function() {
    document.getElementById('div_container').innerHTML = youtube_code;
};
</script>
<body onLoad="writeIt();">
<div id="div_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a trick I learned early on: 

If you instead load this script from an external file say youtube_code.js, you will overcome the 'click to activate this script' prompt at the user-end. Just an FYI :P

Answer (score 1):

Recommend: use a well established, tried and tested js library like swfobject instead.

Comment: this page must be really fast, for that reason I'm trying to avoid include extra js files. 
In addition, I have a fake img of the video and I'm doing this async insertion on img click to get a faster rendering time.